# Is there a way to clean Google Drive trashcan in Google Colab?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab linked with Google Drive for a ML project in Pytorch. However after some time my trashcan gets full with files and I run out of storage, which prevents the notebook from saving updates. Now I manually delete my trash from my Google Drive every time, would there be a way to implement this in my code e.g., a function call I could do after training each model.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `emptyTrash` api call can be used to permanently delete all of the user's trashed files.

HTTP request

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/trash
```

[Google emptyTrash API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/emptyTrash)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I have been struggling to add this in my python script, do you have a suggestion on how to do this? More precisely how do I call this from within Python and how do I get the authorization?

Comment: https://www.example-code.com/python/google_drive_empty_trash.asp  this might help you

Answer (score 0):

We can run these codes in google colab successfully:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/root/gdrive', force_remount=True)

from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
drive_service.files().emptyTrash().execute()
```

but if there're many files in the google drive trash bin, we still need to wait for over 20 minutes, sad.

The rclone command has a immediate effect:

```
!curl https://rclone.org/install.sh | bash
!rclone config    # to set google drive client id etc

#delete all files in trash and don't put them in trash again:
!rclone --config /root/sing/rclone.conf delete gdrive: --drive-trashed-only --drive-use-trash=false
!rclone --config /root/sing/rclone.conf ls gdrive: --drive-trashed-only --fast-list
```